# Why child process only keeps the old version of variable after I re-clarify it?

Tags: c++, process, fork

Why child process only keeps the old version of variable after I re-clarify it(with the same name) ?

Hi, I just tried to run the following code

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int a = 3;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
        cout << getpid() << " " << a << endl;
        int a = 0;
        if (fork() == 0) {
            continue;
        }
        break;
    }
    wait(0);
    exit(0);
}
```

The output is

```
11470 3
11471 3
11472 3
```

Does anybody know why the output is not 0?

Comment: Do not tag C for C++ questions.

Answer (score 1):

The scope of the 2nd instance of `a`, which is initialized to 0, starts with its initialization and extends to the end of its block.

Your `cout` statement appears before the 2nd instance of `a` is declared, and the referenced `a` is the first one, the one that gets initialized to 3.

`int a=0;` declares a different variable named `a`, it has no effect on the first variable named `a`.

This has nothing to do, whatsoever, with `fork` or child processes. If you get rid of the `fork`, execute a simple loop three times, declare `int a=0;` the same way, as in the shown code, and with `cout` appearing beforehand, this will produce the same output.

Answer (score 0):

Your code declares a *new* variable `a`. To assign a new value to *existing* variable, do this instead:

```
  // int a = 0;  << don't do that
  a = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

In the for loop you use `int a = 0;` , which will create a new variable in the for loop's block, rather than modify the variable `a` declared outside.